# transaction management for remote call

Tags: java, transactions

I need to do transaction management for remote SOAP calls. What is the best possible
strategy in Java?

Comment: From where do you need to manage the transaction? What are your requirements? Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: I have an app which calls different data sources using web services.
I want to manage these things using transactions. and i am using spring web services

Comment: This is still not clear. Take some time to explain what you're trying to achieve (and where you want to start and control your transactions).

Answer (score 3):

Using ACID transactions for long-running remote calls might not be a good idea. Mark Little and Bruce Martin discuss the key ideas [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365143/ACID-is-Good-Take-it-in-Short-Doses), which might provide some good ideas on how to use compensating transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like JTA or roll your own approach, though this can be somewhat painful, since you have to ensure your webservices can support transactional semantics (e.g. rollback) and there is some risk in that if the calling application controls the transactions (most common) then you run some risk if that application/session dies.